# HTML5 - input type "submit" does not show button in English

Tags: html, button, input, submit

Just a quick question: I'm playing around in html5, and when I put both a button and an input (type "submit") tags in my html I see two buttons - the button with the word "submit" on it, and the input one with the same word but not in English, but in my native language. I wonder - why is that? Is it because of my browser language? If so, how do I change it?

Thanks,
yishai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying?
You can do this way

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: the value atributte did the trick! I still don't understand why by default the input submit shows an input with non english line.